# EWS Java Api - Extended Properties and privileges to set/get

Tags: properties, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, privileges

I have a short question about MS Exchange Server. I want to sign messages by custom ExtendedProperty on client mailboxes but I want to know that is there possibility to block privileges to set/get/create ExtendedProperties for me by Exchange Server Admin if I have read privileges to read mailbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't do that the owner of the Mailbox will always have rights to do what they want to any message in their own mailbox. IRM is probably more what you need to look at for a solution like that https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-irm-for-email-messages-bb643d33-4a3f-4ac7-9770-fd50d95f58dc.

The other way to do this is have an external service that stores whatever verification you need and then match that to something like the internetMessageId and a checksum.

Comment: Ok, but If I have a mailbox "A" (no direct access for me) where business emails is stored and mailbox "B" which has permissions to access to mailbox "A" and its messages - is it possible that administrator which give me access to account "B" can restrict permissions to set flag/property on messages from mailbox "A"?

Comment: if you have write access to a particular object, you can set any property on it. There is really no difference between a "regular" and extended property. Now *creating* a new (for that mailbox) property might be restricted - the mappings (GUID/id vs MAPI prop tag) are mailbox wide; not sure what is the minimum privilege you will need to create a new mapping.

Comment: What are actually trying to archive though ? If you have your own extended property your code is going to be reading/writing it exclusively so why not just implement logic at you code layer the controls the write access.

Comment: @GlenScales I cannot control write access from my code layer because i'm not an admin of Exchange server. I've been trying to track some special messages by setting this property to reduce costs of used memory on my side, but there is not a good idea I see, so I'm going to find another solution.

Comment: Here is 90% of informations which I asked for (there is a table of possibility to restrict access for me):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-set-folder-permissions-for-another-user-by-using-ews-in-exchange

The next 10% is experimental. Thanks for answers.